# VS Code Highlight Text Mate Rules Priority

Tags: visual-studio-code, crystal-lang

Is there a way to make the `meta.function-call` text mate rule to take precedence over `entity.name.function`?

In VS Code Crystal (Ruby-like language) setting both method definition and method call marked with the `entity.name.function` token.

I would like to have method definition as bold but method calls as not bold. But it doesn't work as I can't override `entity.name.function` with `meta.function-call`

[image]

My `setting.json`:

```
{
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": [
          "entity.name.function"
        ],
        "settings": { "foreground": "#3730A3", "fontStyle": "bold" }
      },
      {
        "scope": [
          "meta.function-call"
        ],
        "settings": { "foreground": "#111827", "fontStyle": "" }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify multiple scopes delimited by whitespace:

```js
{
    "name": "function definition",
    "scope": [
        "entity.name.function"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#ff0000"
    }
},
{
    "name": "function call",
    "scope": [
        "meta.function-call entity.name.function"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#0000ff"
    }
},
```